# How to load @1x iPad images as @2x images on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uikit

I am working on a universal app with hundreds of background images. To save disk space and prevent further duplication and disk spamming I want to reuse the non-retina @1x iPad images as retina @2x iPhone images.

Example:

```
background125_iPad@2x.png
background125_iPad.png
```

iPhone 4 and 5 have a different aspect ratio so I will scale the 1024x768 images to fit.

But the problem is, if I use this on iPhone 5:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background125_iPad.png"];
```

then iOS will try to be smarter than me and pick the huge memory monster @"background125_iPad@2x.png" version.

Is there a way of saying: "iOS, look. I am smarter than you. I want that you load this file. And I really mean this file. THIS one. And treat it as if it was a @2x version with a scale factor of 2." such that it really loads the requested "background125_iPad.png" file, but then UIImageView acts as if it had 512 x 384 points (= 1024x768 px)?

I assume `UIImage imageNamed` is not the way to go then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can turn off that functionality.

But you can always do that:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background125_iPad" ofType:@"png"]];
UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[img CGImage] 
                          scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
                             orientation:img.imageOrientation];
```

That will not add automatically device specific postfixes. 
I would recommend encapsulating that into UIImage category for simpler usage :)

Comment: Yes, that seems to load the correct image, but the scale factor is wrong. iOS should treat it as a @2x image. How would you do that?

Comment: Did you try just scaling it to [UIScreen mainScreen].scale ?

Comment: scale is readonly if I am not mistaken. But maybe I found the solution to the scaling. See my answer (credited you :-) )

Answer (score 1):

To load the image exactly as specified and get the scale factor right, this should work:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"background125_iPad" ofType:@"png"]];
img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[tmpImage CGImage]
                                           scale:[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
                                     orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Thanks to Grzegorz for the `-imageWithContentsOfFile:` and `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` hint.

Comment: But than you have a problem for other devices :) Better use [UIScreen mainScreen].scale

Comment: I updated my answer - orientation you can take from img as well which is better imho